# How to validate the state of a join model before creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

As I got downvoted the first time, this time I try to be as clear as possible about my goals. If they're not clear, please let me know what's missing.

---

I have course and students which have a has_many through: relationship. When I create a record for a newCourseParticipation, I would like to check if the course is already full (via the full? method).

What is the best way to do that? My first impulse was to introduce a conditional check in the Create action of the controller, now I'm doing the validation in the Course model. But I think it would best be a "before_create" validation in the CourseParticipation model. Not sure how to do this though.

My Course model

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students, through: course_participations
  has_many :course_participations
end
```

And my Student model

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses, through: course_participations
end
```

The join model

```
class CourseParticipation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :course
end
```

In the UsersController:

```
def create
  @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
  @student = Student.find_or_create_by(user_params)
  if @student
    @course.participate(@student)
  end
end
```

In the Course model:

```
  def full?
    self.students.count >= self.max_students
  end

  def participate(student)
    if !self.full?
      course_booking = CourseParticipation.new(course_id: self.id, student_id: student.id)
      course_booking.save
    else
      self.errors.add(:course_full, "course is full")
    end
  end
```

Goal:

- Best place to validate that course is not full and create an instance of CourseParticipation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class CourseParticipation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :course

  before_create :check_class_size

  private
  def check_class_size
    !self.course.full?
  end
end
```